# eclipse maven plugin problem

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I try to build project from eclipse with maven and it tells me

```
Build errors; org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) on project sceneExplorer: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources failed.
```

but if I build project from command line all goes perfect all resources are copied and no errors are thrown
command line and eclipse use the same maven installation and settings.xml file

why does it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

heh, problem was in synchronization with file system, I have refreshed project in project explorer and problem has gone